# Compiling using g++, yet still get undefined references to operator new

Tags: c++, g++, ld

I'm compiling using g++, yet when it goes to compile the files in the depend file that's in the same directory as the Makefile, I get a

```
undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
```

Thanks.

Edit:

You're right.

How do you use g++ as the linker instead of ld in the context of the Makefile. Been searching but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @gargob: Post how you are compiling the program & show us the relevant code where it is being used.

Comment: @Gargob In response to your edit: `make` does the right thing by default. We don’t know how you’ve configured it.

Answer (score 4):

The tags of your question suggest that you are using `ld` for linking. Don’t do that; use `g++` instead. This will cause the c++stdlib static library to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

This g++ is an embedded compiler (code sourcery for arm). You should tag your question as embedded and/or arm. The compiler wants to tell you that you have to implement _write, _close_r, ... yourself.

Have a look at:
http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/doc7616/libc.pdf.  It describes what the signature is for the functions you need to implement.